# C# How to change width of border rapidly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make slide in animation.
I want to do it by increasing the border width.
To visualize, I have a border that is behind an ellipse and to make it slide in I want to rapidly increase its width like shown in code.

```
while(Border.Width < 150)
{
      Border.Width += 4;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(70);
}
```

The problem is that it wont increase width of border until the whole process is finished no matter if I stop the thread for 70ms or 1000ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is you're blocking the UI thread with that thread.sleep so it can't do anything until you stop blocking it.

You could make your parent method async and use:

```
await.Task.Delay(70);
```

Instead of sleep.

But you should really look into animations.

[WPF Animation of border width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295190/wpf-animation-of-border-width)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is synchronous.Your should use the asynchronous code.Like Task.Factory.StartNew() if you are use .net framework 4.0.if the .net framework is above .net framework 4.0.you can use async/await keyword.